# Azure Web Application recycle unknown cause

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

I have two web applications running on the same resource group (west europe).

**Every day (5-10 times at day, at different hours) they recycle at the same time with no reason.**

The **Application_End** event shows as **ShutdownReason: HostingEnvironment**.

How can i understand what is going wrong?

---

### Some informations about the environment

1. **No files are touched** in the application folder, so this is not the cause of recycle (and this is confirmed by the ShutdownReason value).
2. The application on Azure has **Always On** activated anche the web server logs confirm that the azure service is polling it keeping it alive.
3. **No visible or logged errors**. I log both applications in the Application_Error but there is no reason logged in. I also turned on the Azure trace but i cannot see something useful in LogFiles folder.
4. The Web application and database related monitors confirm that nothing of interesting is running: **no peeks of CPU or DTU, no I\O issues**, sometimes no requests at all in progress. I want to **exclude also an OutOfMemory** cause is not logged in kudu or other log folders.
5. No management services operation logs in these dates, so noone touched the web applications.

---

### Here are some logs

### Application_Error logs

- **Application** | **UTC Time** | **ShutdownReason**
- Web Application 1 | 2016-04-21 01:17:28.2962 | HostingEnvironment
- Web Application 1 | 2016-04-21 19:17:28.6035 | HostingEnvironment
- Web Application 1 | 2016-04-22 06:30:57.8925 | HostingEnvironment
- Web Application 2 | 2016-04-21 01:17:12.5717 | HostingEnvironment
- Web Application 2 | 2016-04-21 19:17:24.9001 | HostingEnvironment
- Web Application 2 | 2016-04-22 06:30:45.5781 | ConfigurationChange

### Web Server Requests

On the web log i can see only normal requests with status 200 done by the always on feature. No other calls at the time from some connected user.

### Kudu

Kudu logs the immediate restart after the shutdown with this:

```
<step title="Startup Request" date="2016-04-20T13:16:26.394" instance="2754ac" url="/" method="GET" type="request" pid="8272,2,6" ScmType="None" >  
<step title="Cleanup Xml Logs" date="2016-04-20T13:16:26.427" /><!-- duration: 13ms --></step><!-- duration: 47ms -->
```

There is not a related log of the previous stop. When i stop it manually i can see a similar log row, but in this suspected cases there isn't.

### Web Job related

The web job related (Daas: the Diagnostics as a Service job of Azure) logs print that:

- This is a normal restart operation on the related to the Web Application 2 (same time of the 3rd error the ConfigurationChange one):
- [04/22/2016 08:45:23 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
- [04/22/2016 08:45:23 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
- [04/22/2016 08:45:29 > 2754ac: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
- [04/22/2016 08:45:29 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
- [04/22/2016 08:45:29 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped

And this is the log during the unknown reason recycle:

- [04/22/2016 06:31:24 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
- [04/22/2016 06:31:25 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
- [04/22/2016 06:31:34 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
- [04/22/2016 06:31:35 > 2754ac: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
- [04/22/2016 06:31:35 > 2754ac: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted

this seems correct due to the related row of log:

- Web Application 2 | 2016-04-22 06:30:45.5781 | ConfigurationChange

This ConfigurationChange maybe is related to a certiphicate change that is expired today and maybe azure need to exchande it with the new one so, probably the configurationChange recycle is related to another cause.

---

Thanks, Mazzanti Luca